# Why is this question closed as being 'primarily opinion based'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The question [What makes Swift's "Optional" safer than Objective-C's "nil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546224/what-advantage-of-using-optional-in-swift-over-nil-in-objective-c)  is closed for being an opinion based.

If you see this page about [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional), clearly Apple is attempting to show its advantages for safer and more clear code.

If we are to close such questions then we could also close a multitude of other questions like:

- [Swift: guard vs if let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-guard-vs-if-let)
- [Why Choose Struct Over Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class)

I don't think the site benefits from this level of strictness. I wanted to vote for it to be reopened but because of the high reps who closed the question, I doubted and thought I ask for clarification from meta of why that question is considered opinion based and the other 2 aren't?

Comment: I agree that there's a reasonable question there, it was just *very* poorly formatted. I took a stab at revising it, but I'm not a domain expert here, so someone else could probably do an even better job. Nevertheless, I've cast a vote to re-open.

Comment: @CodyGray Your edit only *solidifies* the fact that the question is asking for opinions, given that you edited it to specifically ask for people's personal preferences (i.e. their opinions).

Comment: I strongly disagree. There are objective, technical answers to the question as posed.

Comment: not sure what happened, but the question's link is no longer available as if it's deleted... :/

Comment: @CodyGray No, there *aren't*.  There is no *objective* answer to the question of why someone should prefer one thing over another.  It is *by definition* a personal preference.  You're arguing that you don't *care* that the question is asking for opinions, not that it isn't asking for opinions.

Comment: @Honey: It's deleted, because ostensibly folks are so embarrassed by that question they feel that it's not worth discussing and needs to go. (To be fair, before Cody's edit it *was* pretty embarrassingly bad...)

Comment: *"You're arguing that you don't care that the question is asking for opinions, not that it isn't asking for opinions."* It's very frustrating to have a discussion with you, @Servy, because every time, you insist that people are claiming things that are entirely opposite of what they just got finished saying. There are objective, technical reasons why certain solutions are preferable to other solutions.

Comment: @BoltClock Not sure if someone is abusing their power...anyhow should I delete this meta question now!? :/

Comment: @Honey: No one is abusing their power. This discussion is worth having in any case.

Comment: @CodyGray If the answer is objectively correct, then it ceases to be a preference; it's simply a fact.  There are *subjective* reasons for why people prefer things.  They of course need to be subjective because if they *aren't* subjective then *it's not a preference anymore*.

Comment: I am unable to make sense of that comment. It is precisely my point that this is neither a preference nor subjective.

Comment: @BoltClock there's nothing to talk about...if there is no point of reference. Not sure how that's not obvious to you?! If it's poorly written, then it can be edited. It had many answers/views. I'm embarrassed as to why it was deleted....

Comment: @Servy is asking between 'switch' and 'if else' also an opinion based? Seriously there is no room of discussion this way

Comment: @CodyGray You edited the question to specifically ask for people's preferences.  To quote the question: "why should I prefer to [...]".  So yes, **you** think that the question is asking for people's preferences, given that you edited it to ask for them explicitly.

Comment: @Honey It would depend on how the question is worded.  If it was just asking which people preferred to use, then yes, it would absolutely be asking for opinions.  If it asked a question that had an objectively verifiably answer that was either correct or incorrect, rather than an opinion, then it wouldn't be primarily opinion based.   You're correct that there isn't room for discussion as to which questions asking for people's personal opinions are appropriate (none are).  It's not that some are acceptable and some aren't.

Comment: I think removing the word "prefer" or the clause "why should I prefer to use optional" would do wonders for the question, @Cody. All it seems to do is trip the walking word filters.

Comment: I guess my phrasing was too colloquial and therefore incompatible with the hyper-literal. Revised again. I agree that there's no point in obsessing over a single word.

Comment: By the way, I can't seem to find any direct references to Objective-C in the linked document anymore. No idea if that makes the question obsolete in some way, but if there were such references at the time the question was posted, best if we could get hold of them somehow...

Comment: @CodyGray And of course you've now fallen into the same trap that basically always happens when a "which is better" question is asked, namely you edited to say, "what are all of the differences between these two things", which has simply turned the question from Primarily Opinion based, into Too Broad (while also completely changing what the question is asking, which isn't even appropriate as an edit in the first place, by the way).  You haven't actually made the question no longer close worthy.

Comment: @BoltClock I object to the classification as walking word filter.  The question isn't [just] opinion based because it contains the word "prefer", but rather the user of the word makes it unambiguously clear that the question is indeed asking for opinions.  It's not that the question has verifiably correct answers but just happened to use the word "prefer" in it somewhere, the question is (or was, until it was completely changed to be Too Broad) inherently asking for people's personal preferences.  That's not being a walking word filter, that's simply understanding what the question is asking.

Comment: @Servy And of course you've now fallen into the same trap that basically always happens when someone who interprets language hyper-literally tries to understand normal human communication. I didn't use the word "all"; you inserted that all on your own. It isn't asking for an exhaustive list, it is asking for a technical summary. If the difference is not self-evident to you, I don't know what else I could say, or how else I could modify the wording, to make it more clear. I'd say you could edit if you don't like my wording, but the *real* issue is that you just don't like the question.

Comment: @CodyGray When someone asks, "what are the differences between A and B", they *are* asking for all of the differences.  If it were asking for certain differences, then it would need to say as much.  And of course if it's *not* asking for all of them, then for the question to actually have an objectively correct answer it'd need to specify which differences it's asking for (using criteria that aren't subjective).

Comment: This is just another example of the rampant misuse of the opinion-based close reason. I'm waiting for the day that someone votes to close the question asking "Is the earth flat?" for this reason--since after all, there are people with the opinion that it **is**, and I mean, who are we to say? Many questions closed for this reason actually deserve reasoned answers outlining alternative approaches and their pros and cons.

Comment: I feel this is less a question about opinion-based questions and more about to what extent one should stick to the "letter" vs the "spirit" of the law when imposing such constraints. _Everything_ is opinion-based to some level; even when you're providing a highly-specific answer to a focused question, it reflects your "opinion" on how that problem should be solved. Where do we draw the line? The rationale and "spirit of the law" for closing opinion-based questions is that "they are likely to lead to drawn-out discussions that are unlikely to be of practical benefit to users visiting the site".

Comment: ... (cont'd) therefore this should be the criterion on whether a question should be closed as opinion-based or not. Its practical value (hopefully coupled with limited potential for extended troll-like discussions). Not whether it "fulfils certain criteria on what technically constitutes an 'opinion' or not".

Comment: @Servy you are repeatedly making absolute judgements about what other people mean when they write certain words. That's wrong. Stop it.

Comment: @barbecue I'm making judgements about what people say.  If they mean something that's the exact opposite of what they're saying, then they shouldn't be surprised when people act based on what they actually wrote.

Comment: @torazaburo So then what *is* an appropriate use of the close reason?  If you don't think "which language feature do you prefer" is opinion based, then *what is*?

Comment: @servy your mistake is in assuming that what someone else meant by a word must always conform to a single specific meaning which you hold in your head. "There is no objective answer to the question of why someone should prefer one thing over another." is a perfect example.

Comment: @barbecue So what is the "alternate meaning" of that word that would indicate it's *not* asking for a preference, but instead some objectively verifiable criteria.  I'd love to see a source on that.

Comment: @Servy "Which language feature do you prefer" is certainly opinion-based. This question is not of that form. Perhaps the close reason should be renamed "purely a matter of preference" to avoid the confusion we have seen here about questions asking **about** "opinions" (although it's weird to call a language design choice an opinion anyway), rather than asking **for** opinions.

Comment: @torazaburo But this question *is* asking *for* opinions.  It's asking people to give their personal preferences on what language features they like and don't like.

Comment: @Servy  I never stated that the word "prefer" could mean "objectively verifiable criteria" and I'm not wasting my time chasing your false dichotomy that the word "prefer" MUST mean either a personal opinion OR an objective verifiable criterion, and no other meanings are possible. Language isn't math. "Prefer" can mean a tendency. It can also mean a presentation or submission of information to be considered. It can also mean to assign or give priority to. The fact that a preference is stated does NOT mean it's pure opinion and no facts are involved. THAT is your error.

Comment: @barbecue None of your subtlety different definitions make the useage any less subjective.  Asking for someone's personal tendencies, versus their personal priorities, *are still opinions*.  It doesn't change the fact that the question has no correct answer.  If you state that you tend to do one thing, that cannot be considered "correct" or "incorrect", it's just what *you* prefer, and someone else can prefer something else.  That means that the question is asking for opinions *and that's not what we want here on SO*.  So the possible differences in interpretation aren't relevant here.

Comment: @Servy it's your opinion that preferences are entirely opinions with no factual basis. My opinion is that preferences may be informed by factual information, and therefore not entirely opinions. You believe that no opinions should ever be stated on SO, and yet you continue to state your opinion that no opinions should ever be stated on SO.

Comment: @barbecue No, I'm stating *as objective fact*, that questions that are asking for opinions are violating SO's policy that questions should not be primarily opinion based.  This of course doesn't mean that no opinion can be stated on the site, but rather than a question can't be *asking for opinions*.  Your opinion is that you don't like SO's policy and want people to flagrantly disregard it.  If you want the policy changed, then propose that it be changed, but *until* it's changed, expect it to be enforced.

Comment: @Servy May I kindly ask you continue the discussion on your own answer rather than the question here? I'm getting too many notifications...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My personal opinion is that the question should not be closed as being opinion-based. Apple designed a specific language feature to attempt to avoid problems with an aspect of a previous programming language. The reasoning for this is explained publicly, and you can provide concrete examples of problems that this addresses.

I can think of an objective answer to this that I could write. In fact, the third section of [this blog post](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/12/02/why-were-rewriting-our-robotics-software-swift) I wrote a while back describes specific in-the-field bugs that this language feature can guard against. It isn't really a matter of preferences of style or design, it's what this language feature protects against (and possibly what it handles worse).

I've undeleted the question to allow for this discussion to continue, but I'd support reopening it. I'd be glad to provide a detailed answer if it is.

Comment: "My personal opinion" ***HOW DARE YOU***

Comment: So you think that the question isn't opinion based because Apple has a publicly explained opinion on the subject?  That's rather hypocritical.  Having a publicly stated opinion doesn't make it not an opinion, it just makes it a public opinion.

Comment: @Servy: An opinion can be formed based on facts. If a question is focused on those facts, it's not primarily opinion-based - it just happens to be about one particular opinion. And *that's fine*. As the prose states, "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @Servy - Every aspect of every programming language reflects someone's opinion about how to solve a problem. That doesn't mean that you can't explain what specific problems it solves, or what cases it is or is not safer with than previous designs. The close reason states "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." The answers to this question can indeed be largely based on "facts, references, and specific expertise".

Comment: When the people who design a language have an opinion, they often incorporate it into the design of the language, which effectively enshrines the opinion as fact. More importantly, it creates a situation where effective programmers need to understand the design in order to make reasonable choices. Providing this type of understanding via expert analysis is well within the scope of Stack Overflow. You have to decide which is the real problem: is the question bad because it involves opinions, or because it's subjective? A "public opinion" is quite objective.

Comment: @BradLarson "Every aspect of every programming language reflects someone's opinion about how to solve a problem." Yes, and that's exactly why the close reason is worded as it is, because we don't want, "how do I sort a list" to be closed as opinion based just because there are different sorting algorithms one can use with different merits in different situations.  It's worded as it is so that questions asking for things like, "what language features do you guys like to use" *aren't* being asked, because that's a question with no correct answer, it's a question *inherently* asking for opinions.

Comment: What's funny is the other 2 questions I linked each now have a vote for getting closed. Facepalm!

Comment: @CodyGray No, an opinion of the language designers doesn't cease to become an opinion, nor does it become a fact.  You can argue that it's a more *important* opinion, but it's not any less of an opinion.

Comment: So I guess C# having public, protected, internal, protected internal and private access is just, like, someone's opinion, man.

Comment: @BoltClock No, that they exist is a fact, one that can be proven.  Whether it's a good idea to use those language features in a certain way, over say using a technique more commonly used in another language, is what's an opinion, and even if MS has an opinion on how accessibility keywords should be used, that doesn't make it a fact instead of an opinion.

Comment: The notion that there are objective facts on one side, and pure opinions on the other side, with a pure vacuum between them, is ridiculous. It's a fact that people have opinions, and people form opinions about facts. Human language is not a programming language. Words have multiple meanings, and context matters.

Comment: @BradLarson So what makes this question any different from "Which language should I use, C# or Java?" or "Should I use tabs or spaces when writing my code?" or "What color should I paint my bike shed?"  You can use facts when stating your opinion for any of those questions.

Comment: @Servy This asks about how it's safer, not better. What makes something better than something else is in the eye of the beholder (i.e. functional programming uses more memory but can sometimes result in cleaner code. Is it better or worse?). This question is more akin to "Why is a quicksort faster than a bogosort?" or "Why is a loop more memory-efficient than recursion?" Honestly "Why is encapsulation (a good idea|so prevalent)?" is more opinion-based than this, but still seems like not only a valid question but an *important* question for this site.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson So how do you objectively measure what's safer?  What's not opinion based about that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going out on a limb here because I pretty much agree with *everyone*, and can see their arguments.

My opinion? The question, while asking for opinions, IMHO deserved being reopened.

I don't "frequent" the Swift tag - I restrict myself to it. To those that frequent it, I ask, how many dups do we get about "unexpectedly found nil"? How many others should have been marked as a dup? Bottom line, this is a **core** feature and - three years later, almost four - still confuses everyone.

Forget about that. Just focus on the *core issue*. The OP didn't ask for opinions (at least that I can see, I can't actually see the unedited OP) it asks for *salient differences*. (We need emoji so I can find the duck-behind-couch one now.)

Bottom line for me is that there *are* salient differences between declaring a something as (a) is right now nil, (b) could be nil later, (c) have the compiler help me to make sure I check if it's still nil, and (d) cannot ever be nil. (I'm sure you can come up with more possibilities than these four.)

Are their **opinions** on what is the best way to handle nil? Absolutely. Are there *best practices* that, depending on language, matter? You bet. Are there "pros and cons" to how a specific language handles nil? Definitely.

But as I see the question currently (the only way I know how I can view it on SO), the question is **not** asking that.

Comment: *"I can't actually see the unedited OP"* Yes, you can. Wherever you see an "edited by…" link in the bottom center of a post, you can click on that and see the full revision history. It doesn't require any special privileges. [Here's the revision history for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35546224/revisions). "Salient" was my revised wording, because [I was told that otherwise, the question was asking for an exhaustive list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351953/why-is-this-question-closed-as-being-primarily-opinion-based#comment490860_351953).

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks - I didn't know that about edits. I'll remember that from now on. My instincts *were* telling me that that word may have not been part of the OP. Looking back at the *original* post, I'm amazed at the amount of changes from it there have been. The OP is asking (IMHO) something *very* different that what is there now. Still, asking "how exactly an optional becomes safe" after stating that they are... seems more of a technical question than asking for an opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's asking anything different at all. It's just asking it in a more readable way. The original question is, essentially, stating that optional is safer than nil, and then asking how it "becomes safe". That's the same thing as asking what are the differences in the implementation of optional and nil that make the former safer.

Comment: `it asks for salient differences.`  It was edited to ask a completely different question than what was originally asked, completely invalidating the existing answers, by people also at the same time somehow arguing that it wasn't opinion based all along.  The question author never asked what the differences were.

Answer (score -37):

Just because Apple has an opinion on a subject doesn't a make a subject no longer opinion based.  In fact, it means the opposite; arguing that Apple has an opinion on the subject means that the question you're asking *is opinion based*.

> If we are to close such questions then we could also close a multitude of other questions like:

Yes, those questions are also asking for opinions, although you could also make a case for Too Broad in the latter case ("compare these two things" questions tend to be one or the other, or both).

> I don't think the sites benefits from this level of strictness.

In other words you're saying that you understand that the question *is* asking for opinions, but you just don't *care*, and want to have questions that ask for people's opinion on this site.  This is a subject that has been discussed to death.  You should first read through existing discussions on the topic to see why these questions were made to not be allowed here in the first place, and to read through some of the *many* proposals asking for this policy to go away, and the reasons for why they have been rejected and the policy left standing.

After doing this background research, if you still feel that the policy isn't appropriate, you could write a proposal that demonstrates that  you understand why the policy is put in place, and are able to explain why removing it would be beneficial, or to perhaps explain how you feel the problems with opinion based questions can be removed/mitigated.

Comment: Let's say you're a junior developer. Coding in Objective-C. Then all of a sudden you hear about Swift and everywhere you go you hear a buzz about **optionals**. Makes you curious to know about their differences. At this moment how do you ask your question SO? Or you just never ask the question?

Comment: @Honey No every question belongs on SO.  Fortunately, SO isn't the only resource out there, a simple google search for that question provides lots of resources on the subject of what an optional is, for someone who's not familiar with them and wants to learn more about them.

Comment: FWIW I do agree that the question could have been better, that is the user put in more effort as to what he's learned so far. But closing the question entirely has no basis. Additionally what happens if a person has read them but still can't understand. That the person is an abosolute beginner and is simply looking for some to have a dialogue, that is be able to comment on the answer. SO is to be a place for that person. Going back to my first questions I want to have some of them deleted, but then again and again over time I see those questions getting upvotes, meaning they are still useful..

Comment: @Honey Closing questions is *exactly* the right approach for a question that has problems that need to be resolved.  That's how you get those problems resolved, *so that the question can then be answered*.  If someone reads a broader description of a feature and doesn't understand some specific part of the explanation (and does some research on the subject to see if it's explained better elsewhere) then *that* would be an appropriate SO question.  Asking a specific question about the meaning of a specific aspect of a specific feature is a *great* premise for an SO question.

Comment: @Honey None of that is a reason to ask, "which of these language features is better" on SO.  If the person is really a beginner then it's all the *more* appropriate for them to learn the basics from tutorials, books, etc. rather than going straight to SO.  You say that you want to create a dialog, but SO *isn't* a place to have a dialog, it's a place to have specific questions with specific answers, and where *the dialog is cut out*.  That's the main thing SO tried to do to differentiate itself from it's predecessors.

Comment: @Servy They didn't ask which is better. They asked why A was *safer* than B.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson An earlier revision asked which people prefer, but regardless, how does one objectively determine which one is "safer".

Comment: @Servy No human can ever objectively know anything about anything. All information is gathered through our personal senses and processed in our own minds, and these are both entirely personal and quite unreliable. Therefore, everything is opinions, Stackoverflow is useless and should be shut down.

Comment: @barbecue Of course there are things that you can actually know.  You can't know nearly as much as a lot of people like to think, but there are certainly thinks that can be proven.  The most straightforward example would be math.  You can prove all sorts of things given a set of premises, what you often can't prove is certain basic premises.  That said, the point is not that all questions can only have answers that provide mathematical proof of the answer.  Rather, what's important is that the questions *have a right answer*, even if you can't (practically or not) rigorously prove it.

Comment: This is of course simpler with examples.  If someone asks how to sort an array in JavaScript, you can post an answer that either succeeds or fails to do it, and you can demonstrate whether a given answer succeeds or fails at that task. Objectively whether a given answer accomplishes that is either true or false, even if rigorously proving it is not practical.  Conversely, if someone asks what color they should paint their bike shed, there is no "correct" answer.  There isn't even a metric for evaluating the quality of one.

Comment: Re the "correct" answer for shed painting: 1. You live in a deed restricted community which requires use of specific colors for all buildings. Failure to comply results in fines. GIVEN that you want to avoid fines, there IS a factually correct objective answer to the question. It's not P implies Q, it's Given R, P implies Q.

Comment: 2. Some colors reflect more light than others, so if you PREFER lighter colors, your shed will be cooler. If you do not care about the shed getting hot, it won't impact your color choice. Again, not P implies Q, but GIVEN R, P implies Q.

Comment: @barbecue Sure, and a question asking what colors someone is legally permitted to paint their shed is therefore a question with a verifiably correct answer.  But a question asking what color people like, or asking someone to choose between several considerations (which don't violate any ordinances) doesn't have a correct answer.

Comment: 3. The purpose of painting the shed is protective, not just decorative, and certain protective paints are only available in certain colors. Choosing a specific color may impact the lifespan of the shed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149022/discussion-between-barbecue-and-servy).